# load data spinner from sqlite and mysql

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I try this [tutorial](http://nielpoenya.blogspot.com/2012/08/tutorial-android-spinner-dari-database.html) to load `Spinner` from `sqlite` and `mysql`.

Tthe tutorial works, but this app can't load from `mysql` twice.

So this app is load `mysql` when first debugging only or when data is empty.

when i try to clear data, the app is load mysql.

I try modificate and create a `button` to update `sqlite` from `mysql` but i dont now how. 
How to create a button to update sqlite from mysql, so when i click the `button`, the `spinner` value is change and load value from `mysql`?

BR

Alex

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9667241/265167

Comment: create database sqlite with load from mysql @YaqubAhmad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are not opening database for deletion :

Change your `SpinnerUpdate` method as in `MySQLite` Activity:

```
private void SpinnerUpdate(){
// database handler
dh = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
dh.loadAll();
}
```

and Change your `loadAll` method as in `DatabaseHandler`:

```
public void loadAll() {

//context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
db.delete(DatabaseHandler.TABLE_LABELS, null, null);
}
```

Comment: how about two spinner @ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: solved @ρяσѕρєя K. in `loadAll` i put `onCreate(db);` after  `db.delete(DatabaseHandler.TABLE_LABELS, null, null);`. and now i use two spinner but with two database :(

Comment: @Alexbelek : then you want to access both databases from Server?

Comment: no, i want to access only one database. i try with two database but its heavy. oh ya @ρяσѕρєя K i have a question again, can you help me?

Comment: i ask about the device @ρяσѕρєя K. `It does not meet our quality standards` . when i ask to stack overflow.